# MySQL: Combining two repetitive queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, php-5.3

I have this in info in a table where sometime the `pd_id` is `NULL`

```
doc_id  doc_title   doc_order   pg_id 
14      a.zip       1           NULL    
15      b.zip       2           NULL    
12      c.zip       1           16  
13      d.zip       2           16      
3       f.doc       3           16      
4       g.doc       4           16
```

When I want to query the item with the pg_id 16, I do this,

```
SELECT * 
FROM root_documents 
WHERE root_documents.pg_id = '16'
```

While when I want query the item without any pd_id, I do this,

```
SELECT * 
FROM root_documents 
WHERE root_documents.pg_id IS NULL
```

I find two queries are repetitive, so I try to this,

```
SELECT * 
FROM root_documents 
WHERE (root_documents.pg_id = ? OR root_documents.pg_id IS NULL)
```

So when I want to get this result only when I query the item with pg_id 16,

```
doc_id  doc_title   doc_order   pg_id 
12      c.zip       1           16  
13      d.zip       2           16      
3       f.doc       3           16      
4       g.doc       4           16
```

But I get all of them intead!

```
doc_id  doc_title   doc_order   pg_id 
14      a.zip       1           NULL    
15      b.zip       2           NULL    
12      c.zip       1           16  
13      d.zip       2           16      
3       f.doc       3           16      
4       g.doc       4           16
```

How can I fix this query,

```
SELECT * 
FROM root_documents 
WHERE (root_documents.pg_id = ? OR root_documents.pg_id IS NULL)
```

Or do I have to repeat the query like I usually do?

**EDIT:**

This answer looks strange to me when I have a parameter to be passed into the placeholder:

`SELECT * 
FROM root_documents 
WHERE (root_documents.pg_id = '16' OR (root_documents.pg_id IS NULL AND '16' IS NULL))`

and when without a parameter,

`SELECT * 
FROM root_documents 
WHERE (root_documents.pg_id = NULL OR (root_documents.pg_id IS NULL AND NULL IS NULL))`

Note that I pass `NULL` into the `placeholder` when no value is returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM root_documents 
WHERE (root_documents.pg_id = ? OR (root_documents.pg_id IS NULL AND ? IS NULL))
```

Comment: yes thanks - this one works for me. but I don't understand this query - why `AND ? IS NULL` at the end bit? Can I just do this - `WHERE (root_documents.pg_id = ? OR (root_documents.pg_id IS NULL AND IS NULL))`?

Comment: The part after the OR is saying "where pg_id is null AND the parameter you passed is null". Both must be true.  Not sure if the other would work because I'm not that familiar with PHP and how it does parameters, just with SQL.

Comment: Got it. Thanks! :-)

It just looks strange to me when I have a parameter to be passed into the placeholder. Please have a look on my edit above. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry : you are using MYSQL... Disregard.

One way is this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM root_documents 
WHERE isnull(root_documents.pg_id, -1) = ?
```

-1 or any value you never expect to find in [root_documents.pg_id]. Then when you want to search for NULL query for that value.

Comment: thanks but it does not work as it returns an error `#1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'isnull'`

Comment: @lauthiamkok Yes I know... I edited my post, I was too quick to respond and missed, right there in BIG letters MySQL ... This query works for MSSQL. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: I haven't worked with MySQL for a long time, so I don't remember how parameters work, but the way I would do it is **Where column1 = param1 or (column1 is null and param1 = X)** (X != all possible values for column1)

Answer (score 0):

You could set the ? to a number when you want that pg_id, or to the string `IS NULL` when you want the ones that are null.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following should work for you(**updated**):

```
SELECT * 
FROM root_documents r1
WHERE (r1.pg_id = ? 
OR (NOT EXISTS 
 (SELECT * FROM FROM root_documents r2 
  WHERE r2.pg_id = ? )
 AND r1.pg_id IS NULL)
```

Comment: got error with this query - `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM root_documents r2 WHERE r2.root_documents.pg_id = '16' ) AND r1.root_do' at line 5`

Comment: sorry, misprint (it should be `r1.pg_id` and `r2.pg_id`, not `r1.root_documents.pg_id` and `r2.root_documents.pg_id` respectively). Fixed